# How to test return values on functions with Chai

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

I'm using Chai + mocha + karma for testing my js...

I've got a simple function that will take a number and add 2:

```
function name(str) {
    return str + ' has come online';
}
```

I receive a assertion error, `AssertionError: expected [Function: add] to be a string` but I'm not sure why since it is a string...

```
describe("Number", function() {
    it("Should return a string value", function() {
        expect(name).to.be.a('string');
    })
});
```

Comment: where is `add` defined? - it seems to be a function?

Comment: @hackerrdave AH sorry typo friend!

Comment: name is indeed a function. Try asserting over the result of calling name ( name() )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The test is throwing an error because it is checking the function `name` itself, not the result of invoking the function. You would need to do:

```
expect(name('something')).to.be.a('string');
```

Comment: what if I want to test a function with some values, but because they are invalid, it won't enter on the function. Is it possible to test with `chai` that the code didn't arrive in a function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `assert` you can do it that way:

```
assert.typeOf(name('someting'),'boolean');
```

You can check the [documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_typeof) for more details